# Yield Stream Update Inside a Listener

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, listener

Is it possible to yield Stream updates within a listener? For example, the user stream is updated here and I have other user related data that I am listening to that I wish to update the same stream with.

```
Stream<void> _authStream() async* {
    authChangesSubscription = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
    await for (User? user in authChangesSubscription) {
        // User updated
        
        // Some other user data updated
        MyChangeNotifier.listen(() {
            // I'd like to yield the stream here.
        });

        yield null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: instead of `async*` method use `StreamController`, more here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller, it reads: "If the events of your stream comes from different parts of your program, and not just from a stream or futures that can traversed by an async function, then use a `StreamController` to create and populate the stream"